# Como fazer para dois apps utilizarem a mesma base de dados no firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

boa tarde!

Estou iniciando no mundo de desenvolvimento para mobile. Gostaria de desenvolver dois apps. Em que o app A grava e lê certos dados e esses dados são visualizados (apenas leitura) pelo app B. Estou utilizando o serviço do Firebase. Por onde começo??

Comment: Só criar os aplicativos no mesmo projeto do firebase

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível. Como o @Matheus disse no comentário acima, um projeto Firebase pode ter "n" aplicativos vinculados a ele, e o banco de dados está vinculado ao projeto, não ao aplicativo.

Mas mesmo que os aplicativos não estejam no mesmo projeto, é possível acessar o banco de dados do outro. Mas neste caso você não usará o arquivo json que você baixa do console, e vai ter que inicializar tudo manualmente no app.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!